# Not understanding what I'm missing in my forLoop function

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I've been trying to figure this out by re-writing my forLoop multiple times, look online for example and even checked out MDN and gotten to the point I need someones help.

Now the test error I get is:

```
1) loops forLoop(array) adds `"I am ${i} strange loop${i === 0 ? '' : 's'}."` to an array 2
 5 times:                                                                                     
 ReferenceError: forLoop is not defined
```

My current code looks like this:

```
function forLoop(array){
 var newArr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  if (i === 1) {
   newArr.push("I am 1 strange loop.")
  } else {
   newArr.push(`I am ${i} strange loop${i === 0 ? '' : 's'}.`)
  }
 }
 return newArr
}
```

Thinking process:

1. I need a loop to iterate the array being place.
2. I need a new array to input something each time we loop around.
3. Call a for loop. Set i to 0 as we will start from there.
4. Find the end point which is less than array.length
5. Place increment since we will be going up from 0 each time we loop.
6. Make if and else statement
7. Add if statement is true to the new array
8. Return the new array in the end

Is there something I'm not understanding or missing? Really can't seem to crack this.

For additional information about the test. The test for this problem is:

```
describe('forLoop(array)', () => {
 it('adds `"I am ${i} strange loop${i === 0 ? \'\' : \'s\'}."` to an array 25   times', () => {
  const [array, t] = makeArray()
  const strangeArray = forLoop(array)

  expect(strangeArray.length).to.equal(t + 25)

  const testArray = strangeArray.slice(array.length)

  for (let i = 0, l = testArray.length; i < l; i++) {
    let s = i === 1 ? "I am 1 strange loop." : `I am ${i} strange loops.`
    expect(testArray[i]).to.equal(s)
  }
})
})
```

Comment: Top code works. Bottom code is some kind of testing framework apparently. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: The test doesn't have access to the function (out of scope). You need to import the file where it is defined or include it in your test files.

Comment: @squint I'm following a pre-bootcamp course. They told us to look at the testing whenever we are stuck. I'm having problem on top. It is saying "loops forLoop(array) adds `"I am ${i} strange loop${i === 0 ? '' : 's'}."` to an array 2
 5 times: " in the problem.

Comment: @squint I'm not getting the 25 times part. I guess that is what is making the program fail in the end. I added the testing incase someone was asking what I need from my code.

Comment: @Dez The test is what I found for this problem. I was told to look at the test if I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

`ReferenceError: forLoop is not defined` means that the Javascript interpreter can't find the function "forLoop".

Possible causes:

- The test and the function are not in the same file and you made a mistake while including the file which contains the function. Make sure  you include your file with the function before the test file.
- The test doesn't have access to the function because it's in a different scope of your application.

I tested the forLoop function myself and it worked for me. I don't think the problem is in the forLoop function.